# Reverse array in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I wrote this to reverse array in OCaml like how I usually do in Java:

```
let reversearray array = let len=Array.length array in
        for i=0 to (len/2) do 
            let temp = array.(i) in
            array.(i) <- array.(len-i-1);
            array.(len-i-1) <- temp done;
        array;;
```

However, this does not seem to work sometimes when there is an even number array.

```
# let a2 = [|"a"; "b"; "c"; "d"; "e"; "f"|];;
val a2 : string array = [|"a"; "b"; "c"; "d"; "e"; "f"|]
# reversearray a2;;
- : string array = [|"f"; "e"; "c"; "d"; "b"; "a"|]
```

Could someone explain what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the length is 2. Your for loop is executing for i = 0 and 1. This reverses the elements twice.

Commonly one writes loops in C-influenced languages like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < len/2; i++)
```

This executes just for i = 0, which does the right thing. OCaml executes the loop for all values *including* the upper value.